# Drools Guvnor data enumeration API

Tags: drools, guvnor

In Guvnor documentation, I know how to define data enumeration and use it in Guvnor. Is it possible to fetch data enumeration from my own Java code?

Answer (score 0):

From Guvnor's documentation:

> Loading enums programmatically: In some cases, people may want to load their enumeration data entirely from external data source (such as a relational database). To do this, you can implement a class that returns a Map. The key of the map is a string (which is the Fact.field name as shown above), and the value is a java.util.List of Strings.

```
public class SampleDataSource2 {
    public Map<String>, List<String> loadData() {
        Map data = new HashMap();
        List d = new ArrayList();
        d.add("value1");
        d.add("value2");
        data.put("Fact.field", d);
        return data;
    }
}
```

> And in the enumeration in the BRMS, you put:

```
=(new SampleDataSource2()).loadData()
```

> The "=" tells it to load the data by executing your code.

Best Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I hope its not too late to answer this.

To load enum from application to guvnor,

1. Build the enum class dynamically from string (in my case enum values is provided by user via GUI)
2. Add it to a jar, convert it to byte array
3. POST it to guvnor as asset (model jar) via REST call
4. Call save repository operation (change in source code of guvnor)

Now enum will be visible as fact in your rule window.

Editing/Deletion of model jar and validation of rules aftermath is something you have to take care.